# Planned end time calculation, considering business hours

Tags: excel, time, excel-2007

I am trying to seek a solution to calculate the Planned end time considering the target in business hours. It shouldn't consider the weekends and Holidays.

Login Time: 8:00 AM
Logout Time: 5:00 PM

Resolution time - 40 Hours,  start - 01/10/2015 08:00:00 AM, Planned end time: 07/10/2015 12:00:00 PM (Expected Time)

Answer (score 1):

Taking into consideration that:

1. Column A has the description of your variables (A1 -> Start, A2 ->Factual Start, A3 -> Resolution Time, A4 -> Login Time, A5 -> Logout Time & A6 -> Planned end time)
2. Column B has the variables itself (B1 -> 01/10/2015 08:00:00 (formatted as TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm), B3 -> 40:00 (formatted as [h]:mm:ss), B4 -> 08:00 (formatted as hh:mm) & B5 -> 17:00 ((formatted as hh:mm))
3. Column C has an array of national holidays (this have to be custom defined, as holidays vary from country to country). For this example, I have just defined C1 for Christmas and C2 for the day after Christmas (in Germany a holiday too). Format: TT.MM.JJJJ
4. In cell B2 you can use the following formula to obtain the factual start date/time to bypass the possibility of defining a start time later than logout, at weekend (European Format from Saturday to Sunday) or in a day that is itself a holiday (from days defined in point 3):

   `=IF(OR(HOUR(B1)>=HOUR(B5),WEEKDAY(B1,11)>5,COUNT(VLOOKUP(B1,C1:C2,1,1))>0),DATE(YEAR(WORKDAY(B1,1,C1:C2)),MONTH(WORKDAY(B1,1,C1:C2)),DAY(WORKDAY(B1,1,C1:C2)))+TIME(HOUR(B4),MINUTE(B4),SECOND(B4)),B1)`
5. In cell B5 you can use the following formula to obtain the planned
   end time

   `=WORKDAY(B2,CEILING((B3+MOD(B2,1)-B$4)/(B$5-B$4),1)-1,$C$1:$C$2)+MOD(B2,1)+B3-CEILING(MOD(B2,1)+B3-B$4,B$5-B$4)+B$5-B$4`

Of course you can adapt the formula to your own structure.

Comment: @pnuts, maybe it's because of my Excel version (German), but 37:30:55 is the 7th type I see under Category: Time (6th type if I change Locale to English (U.S.)). However, Custom Format -> [h]:mm:ss will do the work also. In [this Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16PCDBy6Jru5vb_3tj85z5IsC69YmZa0TfLZQ0iMsvpQ/edit?usp=sharing) you have a working example of the formula.

Comment: Answer edited to take custom defined holidays into consideration

Comment: @agustin Thanks Agustin for your answer.... Its helpful. However there is a slight changes to it, if the start date is after the logout time the calculation should start from the next working day. But the calculation is not happening in that way.

Comment: @MohanRaj, the answer was edited to bypass the possibility of defining a start time later than logout, at weekend (European Format from Saturday to Sunday) or in a day that is itself a holiday. You will need to add an extra row to calculate where the project can be started and, using this new value, calculate the project end as usual.